# retrieve reverse multiple records of rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models product and category.

I am able to make successful queries like Category.products etc.

**Product.rb**

```
belongs_to :category
```

**Category.rb**

```
has_many :products
```

Now I want to retrieve only those categories that has at least one existing product.

I tried like this :

```
 @categories = Category.where(Category.products.present?)
```

# returned error undefined method `products'  also changing to product didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting your comment that you need Categories with products and that the product property with_operator to be true, you can do that query in "rails style" using [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins) and [`merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge):

```
@categories = Category.joins(:products).merge(Product.where(with_operator: true)).uniq
```

Which will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."category_id" = "categories"."id" WHERE "products"."with_operator" = 't'
```

You could also use the rails 4 syntax, as pointed by @yukke:

```
Category.joins(:products).where(products: { with_operator: true }).uniq
```

Comment: Rails merge doesn't generates SQL UNION operator. Your code is equal to next:  Category.joins(:products).where(with_operator: true).uniq

Comment: And is not the intention of merge (read the docs). Merge is there to tell rails that `with_operator` is a condition of the products table and not of categories table.

Comment: If you run `Category.joins(:products).where(with_operator: true).uniq` will return an error because rails will think that `with_operator` is a property of the categories table

Comment: @rockskull, okay. Then it's better to use rails 4 syntax: Category.joins(:products).where(products: { with_operator: true }).uniq

Answer (score 1):

All you need is inner join. It will skip those categories, that has no products. And to add a condition on joined table you can use rails 4 where's syntax:

```
@categories = Category.joins(:products).where(products: { with_operator: true }).uniq
```

It will produce next sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "categories".*
FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."category_id" = "categories"."id"
WHERE "products"."with_operator" = 't'
```

Comment: Why would he need the to_a?

Comment: to_a explicitly runs sql query and converts ActiveRecord::Relation to Array. Of course he can skip it, it's just good practice and my habit also.

Comment: @yukke Now I am facing problem to add second condition to `@categories = Category.joins(:products).uniq.to_a` how can I retrieve also just those category products that has `with_operator: true` ?

Comment: You need categories with products or categories where(with_operator: true) ?

Comment: I need categories with products and product.where(with_operator:true)